# Copy files with Gulp.js

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-sass, del

I've been trying to copy a series of html pages from my src folder to my dist folder using Gulp. I've looked online and for some reason what should normally work is not working for me.

my folder structure is like this:
[image]

Here is my gulpfile:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
        sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
        notify = require('gulp-notify'),
        livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
        del = require('del');       

        //////////////////////////////////////////CLEAN THE DIST
        gulp.task('clean', function() {
        return del(['dist/**/*']);
        });       


        //////////////////////////////////////////COMPILE SCSS
        gulp.task('scss', function() {
        return sass('src/scss/app.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'))
        .pipe(notify('SCSS task complete'));
        });     


        //////////////////////////////////////////COPY ALL HTML TO DIST
        gulp.task('copy', ['scss'], function () {
        return gulp.src(['src/**/*.html'], {
            base: 'src'
            }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
            });


        gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
          gulp.start('copy');
        });
```

I've setup the "copy" task to compile the scss first and then it should copy all the HTML it finds in the src folder into dist. Except it doesn't!
My scss gets compiled and copied as app.css just fine, but the html pages are not.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you are doing anything wrong.  I tried to replicate your test and it npm errored on attempting to install gulp-ruby-sass so I just used gulp-sass with the slight changes below and it worked fine.  Perhaps you have an error in your scss files?  The logError below would help.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
        sass = require('gulp-sass'),
        notify = require('gulp-notify'),
        // livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
        del = require('del');

        //////////////////////////////////////////COMPILE SCSS
        gulp.task('scss', function() {
          return gulp.src(['src/scss/app.scss'])
            .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }).on("error", sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'))
            .pipe(notify('SCSS task complete'));
        });
```

Comment: Hi @mark, Thank you a lot for looking into this. 

The issue though is not with sass, it's with my Copy gulp task. It's not copying my HTML pages from the src folder to the dist folder.

I can't figure out why!

Comment: I understand that.  I am saying that I used gulp-sass and your copy html code and it worked perfectly.  it is an easy thing to try to see if it helps.